# What is the name of the transition where the new image slides left to right over the old?

Tags: transitions

Whats the name of transition where the new image slides left to right over the old?

Answer (score 3):

This transition is called a Wipe.

Comment: Should be a comment??

Comment: Nope, found answer, shared with other members